# Display permanent Widget under AppBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, permanent

I would like to implement small audio player controlls `directly under the AppBar` if an audio is playing. This can be seen in many apps like Telegram.

Example:
[image]

How to realize that in Flutter? `The Player has to be displayed on all Screens!` Like a permanent, sticky one widget.

Comment: You can use a `Stack` widget as a main widget. Then use the `Positioned` widget to stick on the top, and other widgets or screens as child in the `stack`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`toolbarHeight`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/toolbarHeight.html) on [`AppBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html) to get extra spaces, and place `Column`(any widget based on your need) on `title`.

```dart
 appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 100,
        title: Column(
          children: [
            Text("title"),
            Row(
              children: [Icon(Icons.ac_unit)],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: This way I have to explicitly add the Widget on every page. I want to add one and that it stays even when the page is switched.

Comment: for my case, I create a wrapper widget for header and footer, use it as 1st child , you can check [this example where I'm fixing width for every-screen](https://github.com/yeasin50/lisa_fischer/blob/master/lib/configs/config.maxWidthContainer.dart)